What is the purpose of Qt.ClickFocus in qml
I have created a test snippet to understand focus behavior in qml:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        width: 600
        height: 600
        color: "lightgray"

        // Nested rectangles
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width / 2 - 15
            height: parent.height / 2 - 15
            focus: true
            focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                top: parent.top
                leftMargin: 10
                topMargin: 10
            }
            color: "blue"

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus)
                    console.log("blue got focus")
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width / 2 - 15
            height: parent.height / 2 - 15
            focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus
            anchors {
                right: parent.right
                top: parent.top
                rightMargin: 10
                topMargin: 10
            }
            color: "green"

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus)
                    console.log("green got focus")
            }
        }
    }
}

According to docs, Qt.StrongFocus is equivalent of Qt.ClickFocus + Qt.TabFocus.
And it seems that pressing tab changes focus from one item to another, yet clicking doesn't do anything.
Searching for answers about it over internet I always end up with 'just use MouseArea and call forceActiveFocus()'. Ok, that works, but what is the purpose of Qt.ClickFocus then?

I believe it's primarily intended for compatibility with inherited components, as the palette also has no effect by itself within Item. (related: commit, QTBUG-117596)

From Qt Documentation, They mention that "This property was a member of the Control QML".

The reason clicking on your rectangles doesn't seem to change the focus is likely because QtQuick items such as Rectangle don't inherently handle mouse events like clicks. They are visual elements, not interactive controls. For clicking behavior to trigger focus changes, the item would need to handle mouse events actively. This is why adding a MouseArea and using forceActiveFocus() is recommended.
Here’s how you can modify your code to make use of Qt.ClickFocus properly by adding a MouseArea:
Rectangle {
    width: parent.width / 2 - 15
    height: parent.height / 2 - 15
    focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus
    anchors {
        right: parent.right
        top: parent.top
        rightMargin: 10
        topMargin: 10
    }
    color: "green"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            parent.forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }

    onActiveFocusChanged: {
        if (activeFocus)
            console.log("green got focus")
    }
}


Here’s an example using Button as a control, with focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus enabling both keyboard and mouse-based focus changes:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600
    title: "Focus Example with Controls"

    Rectangle {
        width: 600
        height: 600
        color: "lightgray"

        // Blue Button
        Button {
            text: "Blue Button"
            focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus // Allows tabbing and clicking for focus
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                top: parent.top
                leftMargin: 10
                topMargin: 10
            }
            width: parent.width / 2 - 15
            height: parent.height / 2 - 15
            background: Rectangle {
                color: "blue"
                border.color: control.activeFocus ? "yellow" : "black" // Highlight when focused
            }

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus)
                    console.log("Blue Button got focus");
                else
                    console.log("Blue Button lost focus");
            }
        }

        // Green Button
        Button {
            text: "Green Button"
            focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus
            anchors {
                right: parent.right
                top: parent.top
                rightMargin: 10
                topMargin: 10
            }
            width: parent.width / 2 - 15
            height: parent.height / 2 - 15
            background: Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                border.color: control.activeFocus ? "yellow" : "black"
            }

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus)
                    console.log("Green Button got focus");
                else
                    console.log("Green Button lost focus");
            }
        }
    }
}



I don't think this answer is correct. If you are using forceActiveFocus, it doesn't matter what you set focusPolicy to.

@JarMan Well, why should They mention that "This property was a member of the Control QML"?

Well because it's true. focusPolicy was a member of Control, but now they moved it to Item in 6.7. But that's irrelevant to the question of "what does Qt.ClickFocus do?" I don't know the answer to that question, but if you still have to manually catch mouse clicks and call forceActiveFocus, then the answer must be that Qt.ClickFocus does absolutely nothing. It's possible that's true, but it seems unlikely to me.

@JarMan my thoughts exactly. My best guess is that focusPolicy's Qt.ClickFocus is meant to control behavior of manually added MouseArea and forceActiveFocus (to enable/disable it). I see no other explanation.

Controls and Buttons that already take care of mouse and tabbing behaviors and focusPolicy is used to refine those behaviors.
Since you're starting out with Rectangle you're missing out on those default behaviors and you have to build them up yourself, i.e. the need to add MouseArea, checking forcePolicy and calling forceActiveFocus(). Whilst you have the option to build a control from scratch, it's better to customize an existing control (such as Button) to achieve what you want.
In the following example, I replaced Rectangle with Button. I also changed the color property with palette.button.
    Button {
        width: 600
        height: 600
        palette.button: "lightgray"

        // Nested rectangles
        Button {
            width: parent.width / 2 - 15
            height: parent.height / 2 - 15
            focus: true
            focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                top: parent.top
                leftMargin: 10
                topMargin: 10
            }
            palette.button: "blue"

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus)
                    console.log("blue got focus")
            }
        }

        Button {
            width: parent.width / 2 - 15
            height: parent.height / 2 - 15
            focusPolicy: Qt.StrongFocus
            anchors {
                right: parent.right
                top: parent.top
                rightMargin: 10
                topMargin: 10
            }
            palette.button: "green"

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (activeFocus)
                    console.log("green got focus")
            }
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!
Here's another example demonstrating Button with various focusPolicy settings. In all 3 cases, the Button will react to button pressed, however, in the last case, it will not take focus whereas the first two do.
Column {
    Button {
        palette.button: activeFocus ? "lime" : "pink"
        palette.buttonText: pressed ? "red" : "black"
        text: "StrongFocus"
    }
    Button {
        palette.button: activeFocus ? "lime" : "pink"
        palette.buttonText: pressed ? "red" : "black"
        text: "ClickFocus"
        focusPolicy: Qt.ClickFocus
    }
    Button {
        palette.button: activeFocus ? "lime" : "pink"
        palette.buttonText: pressed ? "red" : "black"
        text: "NoFocus"
        focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
    }
}

You can Try it Online!


This is a good answer, but the OP's example was kind of similar to this and didn't work. Do you know why it works for Buttons, but not Rectangles?

Thanks @JarMan. I rewrote my answer based on your comment.
